# Google calender not syncing on Lumia 830

Tags: sync, calendars, google

Why doesn't my Nokia Lumia sync with my Google calendar? And please do not suggest I use Outlook because I have a business email address on google that I cannot change. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide more information. What version of Windows Phone (or Windows 10 Mobile) is your Lumia 830 running? Are the OS and apps up-to-date? Do you get any errors? Is the problem with syncing events *from* the phone to Google Calendar, or vice versa?